# Mapping model to other model using multiple columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two models:

```
public class Destinations
{
    public int DestinationsID { get; set; }
    public virtual Navigation Navigation { get; set; }
}

public class Navigation
{
    public int NavigationID { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public int ParameterValue { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyURL { get; set; }
}
```

There's more to both of them but these are the important bits. When I save a Destination I set the Navigation ParameterName to "Destination" and ParameterValue to the DestinationID.

I can't map the Destination to the Navigation because a navigation is not dependant on a destination at all. It could have any model as the ParameterName and the ParameterValue as the ID of that model (or both of these could even be null as it is only relevant to a page and not any additional model).

So, when I am either viewing a single destination or looping through a list I need to be able to get the Navigation.FriendlyURL. This is why I have added public virtual Navigation Navigation { get; set; }. In my mapping class though I need to be able to get the Navigation according to a ParameterName of "Destination" and ParameterValue of Destinations.DestinationID. This is where I am completely stuck.

I am assuming I need something like this:

```
        this.HasRequired(d => d.Navigation)
            .WithRequiredDependent(WHAT GOES HERE)
            .Map(WHAT GOES HERE)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map the `Navigation` property in `Destinations` you can try something like this

```
    this.HasRequired(d => d.Navigation)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**Edit**
You can not map this relationship but you can build a query to retrieve both with manual relationship fixup.

```
var query = (from d in db.Destinations
        join n in db.Navigations on d.DestinationsID equals n.ParameterValue
                where n.ParameterName == "Destination" 
        select new { d, n }).ToList();

// Display joined groups.
foreach (var group in query)
{
    group.d.Navigation = group.n;
}
```

Comment: The relationship is one to one. It also has no foriegnkey as such but instead it maps via the ParameterName (always "Destination" in this instance) and ParameterValue (the primary key of Destinations) fields in the navigation.

Comment: @DreadPeter In that case it is not possible to map. One-to-One uses shared PK.

Comment: OK, so I have code like so: 
List<Destinations> destinations = db.Destinations.Where(d => d.Active == true && d.DestinationTypeValue == dd.DestinationTypeValue).ToList(); 

Is it possible to have an "Include" on that to add the appropriate Navigation item which I would then be able access through the Model in the view. Even if I have to create a ViewModel (which I would probably also need help on).

Comment: Clearly this doesn't work but something like so:  



   List<Destinations> destinations = db.Destinations.Include(db.Navigation.Where(n => n.ParameterName == "Destination" && n.ParameterValue == d.DestinationID)).Where(d => d.Active == true && d.DestinationTypeValue == dd.DestinationTypeValue).ToList();

Comment: @DreadPeter You can build a query to do that. I'hv edited my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: I can see it's doing the right thing now except I am not sure what model I am supposed to set my view up with. I could create a ViewModel specifically for this except I don't know how to cast "query" as said ViewModel. Currently I am getting the error: 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[DiJ8.Puzzler.Models.Destinations,DiJ8.Puzzler.Models.Navigation]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DiJ8.Puzzler.Models.Destinations]'.

Comment: @DreadPeter Try `var model = query.Select(q => q.d).ToList(); return View(model)`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. I've been doing MVC for all of a month now and the query thing is new to me. I can see that coming in very handy.